# Google Graphs axis order

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have a simple input form that a user would use to input data via drop down/selectors. There are 10 questions each with a rating out of 10.

This data then populates a Google graph on the same page.

The data populates the graph just fine but the axis itself becomes unordered. So 2 could be at the top, 10 in the middle and so on. I have no idea why the axis "breaks" like this.

Please note, I have very little experience with Java and a bit of HTML, this is just me trying to learn but cannot find the answer anywhere, or at least, can't recognize the answer when I see it!

Can anyone help?

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html`enter code here` lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>

</title>
<head>
<style>

   

</style>
</head>
<body>


  <h1>REPORT CARD</h1> 
        
<br>

  <form role="form" id="price" name="price"> 
  <p><b>The brand excels</b></p>
        
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px; color:grey; float:right;" id="DB" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" color="green" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
        <br>
  <p>Relevance:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px; color:grey;float:right" id="RLV" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
    <br>
  <p>Pricing related to Value:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey ;float:right" id="PRV" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>            
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
    
  <p>Positioning:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px; color:grey;float:right" id="PSN" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Consistency:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="CNS" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Brand Portfolio:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="BP" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Marketing Activities:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="MA" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Brand Meaning:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="BM" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Support of the Brand:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="SOB" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
    <br>
    
   
  <p>Brand Equity:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; text-align: center; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="BE" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
  
 
 </form>
   
  <br> </br><br> </br> 
   
</body>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Metrics','Delivering Benefits','Relevance', 'Pricing related to Value','Positioning','Consistency', 'Brand Portfolio','Marketing Activities','Brand Meaning', 'Support of the Brand', 'Brand Equity'],
          [" ", 
          value=document.getElementById("DB").value, 
          value=document.getElementById("RLV").value,
          value=document.getElementById("PRV").value,
          value=document.getElementById("PSN").value, 
          value=document.getElementById("CNS").value,
          value=document.getElementById("BP").value,
          value=document.getElementById("MA").value, 
          value=document.getElementById("BM").value,
          value=document.getElementById("SOB").value,
          value=document.getElementById("BE").value,],

        ]);


        var options = {
 
 
          chart: {
            title: 'XYZ',
            subtitle: '',
          },
          bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
  
    
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data on the y-axis gets out of order because `string` values are being used in the chart data,
instead of `number` values

to correct, you can use `parseInt` to convert the strings to numbers.

```
          [" ", 
          parseInt(document.getElementById("DB").value), 
          parseInt(document.getElementById("RLV").value),
          parseInt(document.getElementById("PRV").value),
          parseInt(document.getElementById("PSN").value), 
          parseInt(document.getElementById("CNS").value),
          parseInt(document.getElementById("BP").value),
          parseInt(document.getElementById("MA").value), 
          parseInt(document.getElementById("BM").value),
          parseInt(document.getElementById("SOB").value),
          parseInt(document.getElementById("BE").value)],
```

see following working snippet...

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html`enter code here` lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>

</title>
<head>
<style>

   

</style>
</head>
<body>


  <h1>REPORT CARD</h1> 
        
<br>

  <form role="form" id="price" name="price"> 
  <p><b>The brand excels</b></p>
        
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px; color:grey; float:right;" id="DB" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" color="green" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
        <br>
  <p>Relevance:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px; color:grey;float:right" id="RLV" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
    <br>
  <p>Pricing related to Value:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey ;float:right" id="PRV" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>            
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
    
  <p>Positioning:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px; color:grey;float:right" id="PSN" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Consistency:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="CNS" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Brand Portfolio:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="BP" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Marketing Activities:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="MA" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Brand Meaning:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="BM" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
     <br>
     
  <p>Support of the Brand:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="SOB" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
                        <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
    <br>
    
   
  <p>Brand Equity:</p>
  <select class="custom-select" style="width:100pt; height:30pt; text-align: center; font-size:15px;color:grey;float:right " id="BE" onchange="drawChart()">
   <option id="itemprice" value="">Please choose</placeholder>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1" >1 </option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="2">2</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="3">3</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="4">4</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="5">5</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="7">7</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="8">8</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="9">9</option>
   <option id="itemprice" value="10">10</option>
  </select>
                
 </p>
  
 
 </form>
   
  <br> </br><br> </br> 
   
</body>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Metrics','Delivering Benefits','Relevance', 'Pricing related to Value','Positioning','Consistency', 'Brand Portfolio','Marketing Activities','Brand Meaning', 'Support of the Brand', 'Brand Equity'],
          [" ", 
          parseInt(document.getElementById("DB").value), 
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("RLV").value),
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("PRV").value),
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("PSN").value), 
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("CNS").value),
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("BP").value),
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("MA").value), 
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("BM").value),
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("SOB").value),
          parseInt(value=document.getElementById("BE").value)],

        ]);


        var options = {
 
 
          chart: {
            title: 'XYZ',
            subtitle: '',
          },
          bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
  
    
  
</html>
```

note: `value=` isn't needed...

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the effort and helping me understand it!